# What is the different between `XlFileFormat` enumeration code -4143 and 56?

Tags: vba, excel

what i see from this [xlfileformat-enumeration-excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlfileformat-enumeration-excel) there are different 'xls' code enumeration.
from the list shown, there is code -4143 (Workbook normal) and 56 (Excel 97-2003 Workbook). both produce the same format 'xls'.
the question is what is the difference and which code is the best ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the `xlExcel8 = 56` for *Excel 97-2003 Workbook* only exists in Excel 2007 or later, where `xlWorkbookNormal = -4143` for *Workbook normal* exists also in prior versions.

So e.g. in Excel 95 `xlWorkbookNormal` would produce an *Excel 95 Workbook* but in Excel 97 it produces a *Excel 97 Workbook*. While `xlExcel8` always produces a *Excel 97-2003 Workbook*. In newer versions both produce a *Excel 97-2003 Workbook*

If you want a specific format always use the specific enumeration eg `xlExcel8` to ensure it. But to make your code compatible to versions below 2007 you should use `xlWorkbookNormal` then.

So you see it depends on your actual Excel version which workbook `xlWorkbookNormal` produces.